# $X^p - a$ is irreducible (Example 2.3 from Milne's Field Theory)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

The following is written in Example 2.3 from Field Theory by JS. Milne:

> Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p \neq 0$ and let $a \in F \setminus F^{p}$. Then $X^p-a$ is **irreducible**

I fail to see how this holds. I also assume that the authors means it's irreducible in $F[X]$. Also if $\beta$ is a root of this polynomial (in some extension field $\Omega$), then how is $X^p - a = (X - \beta)^p$ in $\Omega$?

Comment: For the second, this is just fact that $p$th powers give a homomorphism in characteristic $p$.

Comment: @Randall This is the Frobenius Endomorphism right? It relies on the fact that for Finite Fields, this endomorphism is a automorphism?

Comment: Correct, but it is still a *homo*morphism even in the infinite case, which is all that you need to know that $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$.

Comment: @Randall But $\Omega$ necessarily doesn't have to be a finite field, where this holds right?

Comment: I don't understand.  Where do you need $\Omega$ to be finite in order to apply a result that doesn't need $\Omega$ to be finite?

Comment: We use the fact taht $p$th power gives a homomorphism in characteristic p right? Would this hold in $\Omega$? Our statement $X^p-a = (X-\beta)^p$ holds only in the $F_p$ right?

Comment: $(X-\beta)^p =X^p - \beta^p = X^p-a$ holds in char $p$ no matter if the field is finite or not.  You do NOT need an automorphism for that, just a *homo*morphism.

Comment: @Randall Oh but would the extension field also be a char. $p$ field? If yes, then it makes sense but if not I don't see how this holds

Comment: Of course the extension will have the same characteristic:  they have the same $1$.

Comment: @Randall Ah yes, I remember it now, thanks! Also, would be really great if you could explain Part I (or not, whatever work for you :)

Comment: *Theorem*: If $F$ is a field with characteristic $p$, then $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$ for any $x,y\in F$. *proof*:  We claim that if $1\le k\le p-1$, then $p$ is a divisor of $C_p^k=\frac{p!}{(p-k)!k!}$. In fact, $(p-k)!k!$ is not a multiple of $p$ and  $p!$ is a multiple of $(p-k)!k!$ $\implies$ $(p-1)!$ is a multiple of $(p-k)!k!$ $\implies$ $\frac{p!}{(p-k)!k!}=p\overbrace{\frac{(p-1)!}{(p-k)!k!}}^{\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a multiple of $p$. Now note $(x+y)^p=\sum_{k=0}^p C_p^k x^ky^{p-k}$. The terms do not vanish ($=0$) only if  $k=0$ and $k=p$. Hence $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$, as desired. $\square$

Comment: To find a proof of your original question, you may have a look at Zariski's *Commutative Algebra* volume 1 (GTM $28$), theorem $7$ in chapter $2$.

Comment: @Asigan Found it. I don't think it's as trivial as Milne makes it to be. You can add it as answer (if you want to), I think I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a \in F$ such that $a$ does not have a $p^{th}$ root in $F$. We know that, in $\Omega$, $$x^p-a = (x-\sqrt[p]{a})^p.$$

To show that $x^p-a$ is irreducible in $F[x]$, suppose that $x^p-a = f(x)g(x)$ where $f(x),g(x) \in F[x]$. Then $x^p-a = f(x)g(x)$ in $\Omega$ as well; since fields are unique factorization domains and $x-\sqrt[p]{a}$ is irreducible, this implies that $f(x) = (x-\sqrt[p]{a})^i$ and $g(x) = (x-\sqrt[p]{a})^{p-i}$ with $0\leq i \leq p$.

But $$f(x) = (x-\sqrt[p]{a})^i = x^i -i \cdot \sqrt[p]{a}x^{i-1} + \dots \pm \sqrt[p]{a}^i.$$ We assumed that $\sqrt[p]{a} \not \in F$, and that $f(x) \in F[x]$. But look at the coefficient of $x^{i-1}$ in $f(x)$. If $i$ is not divisible by $p$, then $i$ is a unit (F is a field), which would imply that $\sqrt[p]{a} \in F$. Thus it must be that $i$ divides $p$. By our original assumption that $0\leq i \leq p$, this means that either $f(x)$ is a constant polynomial or a scalar multiple of $x^p-a$.

Thus we have shown that $x^p-a$ is irreducible.

Comment: This can be made slightly more conceptual: Suppose $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^n$ is irreducible over $F$ where $n>1$, then since $\alpha$ also satisfies $f'(x)=n(x-\alpha)^{n-1}$ which has lower degree than $f$ and all coefficients in $F$ as well, we must have $f'(x)$ is a constant. Therefore the leading term $nx^{n-1}$ must be $0$ as $n-1\ge 1$, so $n=0$ in $F$.

Comment: oooh I like that answer better!